# Different Sized Posts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using Rails 5 and 'bootstrap', '4.0.0.alpha3'. Im using Bootstrap Cards and Im having the size of the cards be col-lg-6. What Im trying to do though is for large screens Id like the posts to kind of rotate different sizes. Right now on my index page the posts look like this

```
                           col-lg-6 col-lg-6
                           col-lg-6 col-lg-6 
                           col-lg-6 col-lg-6 
                           col-lg-6 col-lg-6
```

and so on and so on.

So Im trying to add just a little basic styling to it and what Im wanting it to look like is for more posts to have a showing of something like this on my index.

```
                               col-lg-12
                           col-lg-6 col-lg-6
                               col-lg-12
                           col-lg-6 col-lg-6
                               col-lg-12
                           col-lg-6 col-lg-6
```

So basically Im looking for two different card sizes, Im just not sure how to get them to work properly. If you all need to see anymore code Ill gladly add it.

This is the _post.html.erb

```
<div class='col-lg-6'>
 <div class="card">
 <%= link_to post do %>
  <div class="card-topper" style='background-image: url(<%=post.banner_image_url %>);'></div>
<% end %>
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
    <p class='tags'><%= raw post.tags.map { |t| link_to t.name, posts_path(tag: t.name) }.join(', ') %></p>
    <h6 class="published-date"><%= post.display_day_published %></h6>
  <%= link_to post do %>
    <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(post.description, length: 130) %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed the `rails` as the question as it's now doesn't really merit that tag. You can add it back in if there's some `rails` specific issue you're facing.

Comment: I'd say this is a rails issue, since the asker seems to understand how to use Bootstrap, but is having trouble creating a loop in rails to output the required HTML code. However, I agree with the edit since the post contains no rails code.. lol.

Comment: @Toby Yes, if the rails code is causing the issue then the tag should be put back in certainly.